# make text content of a div center in the div

Tags: css

i have a div in my HTML like this:

```
<div id="audio"><span>فایل های صوتی</span></div>
```

the CSS of these 2 elements is like this:

```
#audio{
 width: 100%;
 height: 11%;
 background-color: #3F1954;
}

span{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: btitr;
}
```

i want that the span be center (horizentaly and verticaly) in the div and when i zoom in or zoom out my page it remains center.
if i remove the span tag, with

```
text-align: center;
```

i can make it center(but only horizentaly)
what should i do to make it center verticaly?
should i remove span or it must be remain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers search...

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/06unrygt/

Answer (score -1):

You can add `display: table` in div css and  `vertical-align: middle` ,  `display: table-cell` in span css. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p79qymm4/)

HTML Code:

```
<div id="audio"><span>فایل های صوتی</span></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#audio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #3F1954;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
span {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: btitr;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]